# Updating Document on couchdb with put requests

Tags: python, python-requests, nosql, couchdb, updating

I am trying to update documents on `couchdb` documents and especially the `Id` of the document, and all of that with python put requests. But I don't know how to proceed.
If someone has an idea, tell me!

Comment: Showing your code attempt is essential to receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change a document's id in CouchDB. If you need to do this you will have to

1. Delete the original document `DELETE /<dbname>/<docid>?rev=<rev>` https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/document/common.html#delete--db-docid
2. Create the new document with a new id `PUT /<dbname>/<docid>` https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/document/common.html#put--db-docid

You may update a document at any time, modifying any of the attributes of the document *except* the `_id` field.

Comment: Okay, I have another question, is there a way to recup a value where another is ? Like in sql where we can do SELECT * FROM USERS where name="something" ? I mean, search for the points value where the key name: has for value something else

Comment: Sure. The `POST /<dbname>/_find` endpoint allows querying: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2/api/database/find.html